# Unable to Build using MAVEN with ERROR - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to build a code using maven. But I am stuck with an error.
My system configurations as shown by maven is followning:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.2 (r1056850; 2011-01-09 07:58:10+0700)
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/bhphuc/soft/jdk1.7.0_05/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Following is the Maven trace for the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project SpringExample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[3,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[4,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[5,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[6,31] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[6,0] error: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[7,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[8,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[9,24] error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[11,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Entity
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Table
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[29,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Stock
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[30,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Stock
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[31,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Stock
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[40,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Stock
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[49,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

the pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom.xml fail ???

Comment: you are missing dependencies on jpa, and hibernate (or the jpa implementation you intend yo use)

Comment: Apart from all other things. Upgrade to at least 3.0.5 instead of using an unstable Maven version.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

try to add this dependency in your pom file. Also had you noticed the error

```
[ERROR] /home/bhphuc/Axs/SpringHibernateAnnotationExample/src/main/java/com/mkyong/stock/model/Stock.java:[6,0] error: static import only from classes and interface
```

Did you used any static imports there (in Stock class) ?? Also please check your JDK version.